# I want to retrieve data from db android but Cursor always retuns null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My issue is that when i try to retrieve data from "select * from  TABLE_SEARCH_DETAILS  WHERE   KEY_SEARCH_PAIR + "  'searchPair' method i am getting the Cursor null.The table has all the values needed. I have checked that using db browser. Code is given below.

```
 String getCollectedDataQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_SEARCH_DETAILS + " WHERE " + KEY_SEARCH_PAIR + " = '" + searchPair+" '";

        Cursor getCollectedCursor = groceryAppDatabase.rawQuery(getCollectedDataQuery, null);
    if (getCollectedCursor==null){
        Log.v("NULL","=="+getCollectedCursor);
    }
```

but when i remove where part from Query i gets data.. Anyone knows what is the issue in my "where" part on my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value on rawQuery should be the selectionArgs.  Try this:

```
String getCollectedDataQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_SEARCH_DETAILS + " WHERE " + KEY_SEARCH_PAIR + " = ?";
String[] queryArgs = new String[]{searchPair};


Cursor getCollectedCursor = groceryAppDatabase.rawQuery(getCollectedDataQuery, queryArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  ' at the end of line

```
String getCollectedDataQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_SEARCH_DETAILS + " WHERE " + KEY_SEARCH_PAIR + " = '" + searchPair + "'";

    Cursor getCollectedCursor = groceryAppDatabase.rawQuery(getCollectedDataQuery, null);
if (getCollectedCursor==null){
    Log.v("NULL","=="+getCollectedCursor);
}
```

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. I have edited my question. Added ' at the end but not solved

Comment: How did you make sure the table is filled by value?

Comment: is 'KEY_SEARCH_PAIR' column name? please share the function and how did you call the function

Comment: You have added a additional SPACE at the end of the line which should be deleted " '" to "'"

Comment: String getCollectedDataQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_SEARCH_DETAILS + " WHERE " + KEY_SEARCH_PAIR + " = '" + searchPair+  **" '"**; //HERE